# Matlab user guides in Kindle format

Tags: windows, matlab, kindle

I want to read the Matlab user guides and getting started guides in Kindle format, but I can not find them in Amazon. Someone could show me how to convert a special section in the Help file into the Kindle format to read? A step-by-step guide is very appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: what format are the Matlab user guides in to begin with?

Comment: ohh sorry, I forgot that, I have the pdf and html help file after installing matlab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) and add your pdf to it (html wont work ) .
Then convert your ebook to .mobi format and send it to your kindle .